# Delphi XE2 DataSnap REST - "Out of memory" when i try to download a big file

Tags: delphi, rest, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I created a simple DataSnap REST server in Delphi XE2 and i have a method which returns a TStream object to transfer a file. This works well but when i try to download a big file (~2,5GB) i got an

> "out of memory"

error message on the server side.

I would like to download the file via internet browser (*http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/GetFile*).

Can rest service return big files?

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892334/delphi-xe2-datasnap-download-file-via-tstream-with-progress-bar) and tryed that solution which works well when i use a small file.

Here is my simple code:

```
function TServerMethods1.GetFile: TStream;
var
  FileStream: TFileStream;
begin
  FileStream := TFileStream.Create('d:\file.exe', fmOpenRead);
  Result := FileStream;
end;
```

How can i download a big file from a REST server via internet browser?

Comment: Perhaps you may be able to let Indy serve the content in chunks.

Comment: All decent HTTP server implementations transfer a response stream without loading it first into memory completely (AFAIK Indy does it right so no chunking is required). Looks like DataSnap REST services use a poor implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your function is a `TStream`, try to increase the amount of memory for your application [How can I enable my 32-bit Delphi application to use 4gb of memory on 64-bit windows (via Wow64.exe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849344/how-can-i-enable-my-32-bit-delphi-application-to-use-4gb-of-memory-on-64-bit-win)

Anyway, you are loading a very big amount of data. You should create a function which gives you the result in more small chunks.

Comment: I created a function which gives the result in more small chunks but in this case (i think) i need to use a client application only (not the internet browser).

Comment: I compiled my application into 64-bit platform and now it works. Thank you for your answer!